# transformation of symplectic structure by a matrix

Tags: geometry, matrices, vector-spaces, manifolds, symplectic-geometry

Suppose that in canonical symplectic basis $e_1,e_2,f_1,f_2$ we have 
$$\Omega=pf_1^*\wedge f_2^*+qe_1^*\wedge e_2^*+r(e_1^*\wedge f_2^*+e_2^*\wedge f_1^*)+s(e_1^*\wedge f_1^*-e_2^*\wedge f_2^*)$$
Let $A_t$ be transformation of symplectic structure that depend on the real parameter $t$ and in the basis of $e_1,e_2, f_1, f_2 $ has the following form:

$ \begin{vmatrix}
 1&  0&  0& t\\
 0&  1&  t& 0\\
 0&  0&  1& t\\
 0&  0&  0& 1\\
\end{vmatrix}$

so $A_t$ how act on $\Omega$? in fact how can we find ?s

$ (p,q,r,s)\overset{A_t}{\rightarrow}(?,?,?,?)$